# Shell script: Remove all the space characters in a string

Tags: shell

I work on shell script and I want to remove all space characters in a string. 
On another question I saw a `sed` command for replacing and tried to use it with sending null character in it:

`echo \0 | sed "s/ /${text}/"`

But it did not work.

Any other way to do this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This deletes all space characters in the input:

```
echo some text with spaces | tr -d ' '
```

Another way using `sed`:

```
echo some text with spaces | sed -e 's/ //g'
```

But... In your example there are no spaces, and it looks like you want to replace spaces with the content of the variable `$text`... So not 100% sure this is what you're looking for. So if not, then please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

This was my use case:

Multiple key values that should go on a single string. I'd like to split the string to make them easier to read.

```
SPLIT="          \
KEY_1=$VALUE_1,  \
KEY_2=$VALUE_2,  \
KEY_3=$VALUE_3   \
"

JOINED="$(echo "$SPLIT" | sed "s/ //g")"  # REMOVE SPACES
echo $JOINED
```